# Gcc can't find wine libs

Tags: c++, c, gcc, opensuse, wine

When compiling LMMS I get these errors:

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.6/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lshell32
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.6/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lcomdlg32
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.6/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdi32
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.6/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -ladvapi32
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.6/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -luser32
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.6/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lkernel32
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.6/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lntdll
```

I have both 32 and 64 bit versions of wine and all libs are located in /usr/lib(64)/wine/

What should I do to make it compile with it?

Makefile: http://pastebin.com/kgUe0cW1

Answer (score 0):

Add this opt line in your compile command?
`-L/usr/lib(64)/wine`

Then your ld will found the `.so` file.

Comment: How can I add it to makefile?

Comment: Could you please paste your makefile here? Then bodies can help you fix it~ :)